# In application-settings, iterate the key values

Tags: nativescript

In Nativescript application-settings module, is there a way to iterate through all the key values?

Answer (score 0):

There is no appropriate way to get all keys from the `application-settings` and to iterate through them. You will still need to save somewhere the keys- for example in array, to be able to get the values. For your convenience I am attaching example, however the given code  is not the best practise.
Example:

```
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { HelloWorldModel } from './main-view-model';
import {setString, hasKey, getString, setNumber, getNumber} from "application-settings"

// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
  // Get the event sender
  let page = <Page>args.object;
  var arrayKeys=[{value:"string1", type:"string"}, {value:"string2", type:"string"}, {value:"string3", type:"string"}, {value:"number1", type:"number"}];

  setString("string1", "stringValue1");
  setString("string2", "stringValue2");
  setString("string3", "stringValue3");
  setNumber("number1", 1);
  console.log("--------Get Values----------")
  for(var i=0; i<arrayKeys.length;i++){
    if(hasKey(arrayKeys[i].value)){
      switch (arrayKeys[i].type) {
        case "number":
          console.log("Number "+getNumber(arrayKeys[i].value))
          break;
        case "string":
          console.log("String "+getString(arrayKeys[i].value))
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }

    }
  }

}
```